# Is it possible to call a VSTO plugin and an Office.js plugin from the same Custom Word Tab?

Tags: reactjs, vsto, office-js

Hey Guys I'm currently working on a Word plugin using yeoman with React.

I ran into limitation problems with office.js, issues like not being able to fully edit the ooxml.

VSTO solves these issues for me but I don't have a taskpane as nice as what can be done with office.js

so would it possible to have a word custom tab that say had half the actions call a VSTO plugin and the other half call an office.js plugin?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible today, we track Office Add-in feature requests on our [UserVoice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).  Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.